# How to add character "-" and "`" to the string regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the next source:

```
Matcher mather = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Alnum}*" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}*)").matcher(ssb.toString());
```

But if string = `"fefrefewre-rfrefrf"` or "fefrefewre`rfrefrf"  my mather = **"fefrefewre"**

I need mather  = `"fefrefewre-rfrefrf"` or "fefrefewre`rfrefrf"

How add character "-" and "`"  to the  string regex?

subtext = `"fefref"` - for example

Comment: subtext = "fefref" for example

Comment: So it's a legitimate string that changes?  That's a bit of an unusual regex, then...

Comment: @Makoto I do not understand what you want to ask

Comment: Try to describe the problem better: `-` only has special meaning in a character class and \` has no special meaning in a regular expression. (Showing *real input* and *desired output* - not "mather" - might be beneficial.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want to match the '-' and '`' symbols in addition to the "\p{alpha}".

I think this is the most straightforward solution:

```
Matcher mather = Pattern.compile("((\\p{Alnum}|[\\-`])*" + subtext + "(\\p{Alnum}|[\\-`])*)").matcher(ssb.toString());
```

Comment: Tentatively +1, since I _think_ this is what the question is asking about. One note: unless the hyphen is within a range, you're probably fine excluding the escape slashes.

Comment: @Wiseguy Wasn't sure. But if anything is added to it later (symbols before the dash), it could break. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using POSIX character classes that you don't seem to well understand, you could just add the characters you want to allow to a `[]` character class

```
Matcher mather = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9`-]*" + subtext + "[a-zA-Z0-9`-]*").matcher(ssb.toString());
```

The `-` has to be escaped in a character class unless it is at the start or end of it.

Comment: +1 - This is totally equivalent to my solution, is more succinct, efficient an readable. The only thing I would change is to escape the dash anyway.